# DHT.h Library not being imported

Tags: c++, arduino-uno, electronics

I am trying to read the humidity and temperature using a DHT11 temperature sensor for an Arduino UNO using the `DHT.h` library. I have my code below:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#define dataPin 4
dht DHT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600)

}

void loop() {
  int readData = DHT.read11(dataPin);
  float t = DHT.temperature;
  float h = DHT.humidity;
  Serial.println("Temperature: ")
  Serial.print(t)
  Serial.print(" ºC")
  Serial.println("Humidity: ")
  Serial.print(h)
  Serial.print(" % ")
  delay(2000)
}
```

When compiling the program, it gives me an error:

```
fatal error: DHT.h: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried with lower case letters, but it will not work. Is there any reason why? Do I have to install it? I have tried to search for the library in the Arduino app **Sketch - Include Library - Manage Libraries**, but the library is not there.

Comment: Actually it is a custom library by adafruit. It is present at https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library

Comment: adafruit/DHT-sensor-library is not the correct library for the code in the question. That code is written for a different library, which I have provided instructions for below.

Comment: it seems nothing problem with your library. Have you calibrate your formula(math eq inside coding)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/archive/master.zip
2. Copy the `Arduino-master/libraries/DHTstable` subfolder of the downloaded file to the `libraries` subfolder of your sketchbook folder. You can find the location of your sketchbook folder at **File > Preferences > Sketchbook location** in the Arduino IDE.
3. Change the first line of your sketch from:

   ```cpp
   #include <DHT.h>
   ```

   to:

   ```cpp
   #include <dht.h>
   ```

Now when you try to compile the sketch you will still encounter many errors. However, these are caused by a paucity of semicolons, not by the DHT library, and thus off-topic for this question.

Comment: Thanks, @per1234, now it is not showing an error. But, the readings of humidity and temperature are not correct. Here the temperature is nearly 20-degree Celsius with humidity nearly 60%. But Arduino shows the temperature of 2.3-degree Celsius and humidity of 13%. Why so? How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems using some `DHT` library versions.  I suggest that you try using a different version of `dht.h`

This version works for me (there are [newer versions](http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DHTLib), but I recommend starting with this oldie but goldie):

dht.h (606B 6/12/2012)

```
// 
//    FILE: dht.h
// VERSION: 0.1.00
// PURPOSE: DHT Temperature & Humidity Sensor library for Arduino
//
//     URL: http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DHTLib
//
// HISTORY:
// see dht.cpp file
// 

#ifndef dht_h
#define dht_h

#if ARDUINO >= 100
 #include "Arduino.h"
#else
 #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

#define DHT_LIB_VERSION "0.1.00"

class dht
{
public:
    int read11(uint8_t pin);
    int read22(uint8_t pin);
    double humidity;
    double temperature;

private:
    uint8_t bits[5];  // buffer to receive data
    int read(uint8_t pin);
};
#endif
//
// END OF FILE
//
```

Answer (score 0):

try to download this library in this link and insert it to your ide, it works for me.

https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library